# Windows laptop: how to turn off display with usb device plugged in?

Tags: windows-7, usb, laptop, powershell

I need to plug in a usb device and turn off the display so that I can use the Windows as a headless server. However, I have already tried a couple of methods below but not very successful.

- Window's own power options: doesn't work, display does not turn off after timeout
- watch4idle: similar
- nircmd, pushitoff, monitoroff, powershell script: all these programs behave the same, it turns off the display, but after a while the display turns back on by itself
- presentation mode: display turns off, but turns back on as it cannot find projector

EDIT:

I discover that even I unplug the USB device I still cannot turn off display. When I run nircmd or other program, the display turns off first but after a few seconds it turns back on by itself.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Does your laptop includes a [function key](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/business4/uploads/askfedora/original/2X/c/c0e572e9bc07f932dd7f1bfb704d788a108b1992.jpeg) to turn off the light of your screen? should be arround F5 to F10

Comment: What are the computer model and operating system, and what is this USB device.

Comment: @TamalesRancheros, No it doesn't.

Comment: @harrymc, It is an old model of Dell Inspiron running Windows 7. The USB device is my phone tethering. I later found out it doesn't matter when the device is unplugged, check my edit update.

Comment: Run `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and [sfc /scannow](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html). Let us know the results.

Comment: @harrymc, Please check the results as in attached screenshot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows installation has been corrupted in a way that cannot
be fixed by SFC.

I would suggest as a test to create a new user account to see if the
problem does not occur under it. If the problem disappears, then
your user profile is corrupted and you may migrate your documents
etc. to the new profile.

If under the new profile the problem still appears,
[Do a Repair Install](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

As Windows 7 does not have an up-to-date boot media, I suggest taking
good backups before starting, including a disk image of the entire
disk. Use a third-party product such as AOMEI.
If successful, you may still find yourself with an older Windows 7
version, so you will need to apply all Windows Updates.

My best recommendation would be to use the occasion to migrate to
Windows 10. Windows 7 is a very old product and a big security risk.

Comment: I haven't got time to fix it yet, but I believe it is a wise suggestion to first switch to Win 10. I will let you know how it is going later on. Thank you.